# Why aren't the derivatives of this transformation and its inverse reciprocals of each other?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Consider the coordinate transformation under rotation that
\begin{align}
y' & = y\cos\phi + z\sin\phi \\
z' & = -y\sin\phi + z\cos\phi ,
\end{align}
we can get 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial y'}{\partial y} = \cos\phi .
\end{equation}

From the equations, we also have 
\begin{align}
y & = y'\cos\phi - z'\sin\phi \\
z & = y'\sin\phi + z'\cos\phi ,
\end{align}
from which we can get 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial y'} = \cos\phi .
\end{equation}
My question is, why
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial y'}{\partial y} \neq \frac{1}{\frac{\partial y}{\partial y'}} 
\end{equation}
in this case?

Comment: If you find the Jacobians of both the transformation and its inverse you will see that those two matrices are inverses of each other.  That's what the inverse function theorem means in higher dimensions.  The IFT does *not* say anything about individual partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 transformations in your equation may be written as

$y'=f(y,z)$

$y=g(y',z')$

In your first partial differentiation you are treating $z$ as a constant

$$\frac{\partial y'}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f(y,z)}{\partial y} \bigg | _{z=\text{constant}}$$

In your second partial differentiation you are treating $z'$ as a constant

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial y'}=\frac{\partial g(y',z')}{\partial y'} \bigg | _{z'=\text{constant}}$$

As you can see the 2 Partial derivatives are in general *not* reciprocals of each other.

However The reciprocal rule is true for total derivatives (given that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and their differentials are non-zero)